# How to select last record of each month

Tags: query, oracle-11g

I have a table:

```
Table1(DDate date,Deposit_Key Number , Amount Number)
```

some example data are:

```
DDate       Deposit_key        Amount
1/1/2019          1              10
1/2/2019          1              20
1/3/2019          1              30
1/4/2019          1              40
  ----           ---             ---
1/31/2019         1              100
```

I have data for one month and I need to retrieve the `Amount` for the last day of the month . I mean I need to have `100` . What is the best query possible for this? I'm new to oracle and I want to know whether there are better ways than using row_number() over(partition)?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: I do no need a stored procedure. I just need to retrieve data for the last day of each month @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Then you don't need PL/SQL

Comment: OK . So what is the best way? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: You only need plain SQL, not PL/SQL - PL/SQL is only used to write stored procedures, functions and triggers.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so you mean I have to use row_number()over()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle built in function called [LAST_DAY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions077.htm#SQLRF00654) can help you here.

It can be used with dates or timestamps and an example based on your table description is:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM DDATE) = EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(DDATE))
AND EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DDATE) = 1;
```

There are many ways to work with dates in Oracle but I like using EXTRACT as it works with dates and timestamps and means you don't have to use the TO_CHAR function.

Comment: simpler would be `where trunc(ddate) = last_day(trunc(ddate))`. Maybe without the `trunc`s if the OPs data has the time parts of each date set to midnight.